# zfs dataset disappearing on the filesystem but remains in zfs list

Tags: server, filesystem, backup, zfs

My storage server on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS was now running for half a year, quite stable. It's using zfs (raidZ) for the storage partition.

The server runs somewhat as a backup mirror to another server that uses znapzend to send over snapshots frequently. (I somewhat have the feeling the pool disappears when znapzend starts sending however why only the storage dataset and not the database, I don't know) Both servers should have the same zfs pool-setup if I remember correctly, including snapshots and quota. Both servers recently got a complete system update. The "main" server shows no issues with the datasets, they are not disappearing there.

The pools on the backup have refreservation and refquota set to keep enough space for snapshots.

```
pool                          quota           none       default
pool                          refquota        none       default
pool                          refreservation  none       default
pool/db                       quota           none       default
pool/db                       refquota        100G       local
pool/db                       refreservation  100G       local
pool/storage                  quota           none       default
pool/storage                  refquota        2T         local
pool/storage                  refreservation  2T         local
```

After latest update of the whole Ubuntu system, pool/storage keeps disappearing from filesystem but is still listed in zfs.

```
root@server:~# mount | grep pool
pool on /pool type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
pool/db on /pool/db type zfs (rw,xattr,noacl)
root@server:~# zfs list
NAME         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
pool        2.11T  1.40T   104K  /pool
pool/db   109G  90.6G  9.40G  /pool/db
pool/storage  2.01T  1.39T   629G  /pool/storage
```

My monitoring reports a few times a day pool/storage returning to the filesystem and then disappearing again:

Report from 5:21, dataset came back:

```
Host:     backup
Alias:    backup
Address:  192.168.1.11
Service:  Filesystem /pool/storage
Event:    UNKN -> OK
Output:   OK - 52.9% used (1.06 of 2.00 TB), trend: +342.55 GB / 24 hours
Perfdata: /pool/storage=1109740.5;1677721.6;1887436.8;0;2097152 fs_size=2097152;;;; growth=4962844.988964;;;; trend=350775.45978;;;0;87381.333333
```

Disappears again at 6:07:

```
Host:     backup
Alias:    backup
Address:  192.168.1.11
Service:  Filesystem /pool/storage
Event:    OK -> UNKN
Output:   UNKN - filesystem not found
Perfdata:
```

I don't see anything wrogng in zpool status either

```
root@server:~# zpool status
  pool: pool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 4h43m with 0 errors on Tue Aug 27 15:01:28 2019
config:

                NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
                pool        ONLINE       0     0     0
                  raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
                    sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
                    sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

What's going on here? What can I do to investigate into this behavior?